# Maps API Not Found

Tags: android, google-maps, manifest

**Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that  is in the  element of AndroidManifest.xml**
                                                                             In this case I already declare in android manifest but still got error like that

Here my manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="qualitas.co.id.projectdelivery">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAqTdslgTqsIecwrAMrHvhInn5bqp_5HNY" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

What must i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do this.

put this outside of application tag

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR _ KEY" />
```

put this inside the application tag

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Hope it will help you :)